# Why does my program think a JSON Object reply exists, when it shouldn't?

Tags: java, json, twitch

What we are trying to do is create a bot that will check if someone is a follower of a twitch channel. We return a boolean if they are or are not. In this situation we call a JSON object and use .get("error") to see if it is present. If it is present, we want to return false because that means they are not a follower. If it cannot be found it should throw a JsonIOException, but it never does. If they do follow it returns this: http://pastebin.com/RxvTTZUA which should break because there is no error key. If they are not following it returns this: http://pastebin.com/Qha8UGat which should then return false. This is the code that checks it:

```
    public static boolean isFollower(String channel, String sender) {
    try {
        String nextUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/"+sender+"/follows/channels/"+channel;
                    System.out.println(nextUrl);
        JsonObject following = new JsonParser().parse(new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(nextUrl).openStream()))).getAsJsonObject();
        try {
            following.get("error");
            return false;
        } catch (JsonIOException e) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (JsonIOException | JsonSyntaxException | IOException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "An error occurred checking if "+sender+" is following "+channel.substring(1), e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The println in line 4 is just me trying to figure out the problem myself, but I am pretty confused.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: gson and gson associated files, I think it is the google one

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29), I don't see anything about exceptions being thrown if the key isn't found. You seem to have misunderstood the API you are using?

Comment: Or, maybe you were looking at the [`org.json.JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) class from a different library, where an exception *is* thrown if the key isn't found?

Comment: It worked before though... Weird ok let me check the documentation again.

Comment: Do you think I should do an if statement to check if the thing is not null? That is what the documentation I am looking at seems to say.